# How to compare 3 objects in a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

My string of elementary django questions continues.

If I have three string variables and want to test that one of them, "fullname," is equivalent to two others concatenated, "first" and a space and then "last," how would I go about doing so in the context of a django template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags), that might offer you something like this:

```
{% test_name_equality "Dagobert Duck" "Dagobert" "Duck" %}
```

in the template you can use very normal python string handling.